# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1*2*3' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to write a stored procedure to get value from a formula. I have a formula stored in my table column and I need to replace the variable with a numeric value and get back with calculation.

For example- I have the formula stored as in a table column as varchar : V6 * 1.103 * 0.0078

At runtime I get the V6 to be substituted with a value say suppose = 684. So, I need 684 * 1.103 * 0.0078 = 5.88(decimal rounded to 2 values)

I tried many ways, but I did not get to a solution. The following code is a sample of what I tried:

```
DECLARE @MYFOR AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @MYFOR ='V6*2*3'

SELECT REPLACE(@MYFOR,'V6','1') -- this works and replaces V6 with 1- output is 1*2*3 , but I want with multiplication . I want my output as 6.

select Cast((REPLACE(@MYFOR,'V6','1') as int) -- this fails
Select Convert(integer,@MYFOR) -- this fails.
```

Please help me...How I do get to replace the variable in the formula and then do the multiplication? Please guide me....I really appreciate it...

Comment: There has *got* to be a better place (if this has to be done at all) to do this sort of evaluation than trying to do it down in the database. Despite superficial resemblances in certain environments, SQL tables and Excel spreadsheets are *very* different things

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this either with a special purpose parsing function or dynamic SQL.

You can try:

```
DECLARE @MYFOR AS VARCHAR(100);

SET @MYFOR = 'V6*2*3';

SET @MYFOR = 'SELECT ' + REPLACE(@MYFOR, 'V6', '1');

exec(@MYFOR);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27899) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But, I understand from the other comments how difficult it is do math calculations with string manipulations, I am trying to see at some other efficient method at doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly not a task for SQL and T-SQL. It involves string manipulation, something T-SQL is already not good at, but furthermore it involves a fully fledged lex/grammar parser to understand the expression, and an expression engine to do the evaluation. All these task are something CLR is very very very good at.

Write a lexical parser and an evaluation engine in C# and then use [SQLCLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) to integrate it with SQL. [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html) has an expression evaluation engine. Just google for expression evaluation in C# and you'll find a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all the responses. I am going in a different direction. This was for a report and every time the value V6 changes, I need to get a runtime value based off that formula.

But, I am trying to approach in a different way which might be more efficient than doing in database.